# c# Как скачать видео с vk.com?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, httpclient

С помощью VK API методом video.get получил ссылку на видео: [Ссылка на видео](https://vk.com//video_ext.php?oid=-63632654&id=456261113&hash=75d087e04edecbfe&__ref=vk.android&api_hash=1606065107bb8990302df4d045c2_GMYDEMRRHEYTCNY)

Пробовал скачивать вот так:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        { 
            File.WriteAllBytes( @"\img\video.mp4",
            await client.GetByteArrayAsync(@"https://vk.com//video_ext.php?oid=-63632654&id=456261113&hash=75d087e04edecbfe&__ref=vk.android&api_hash=1606065107bb8990302df4d045c2_GMYDEMRRHEYTCNY")); 
        }
```

Но загружается .html файл.
Как можно скачать видео с вконтакте?
Спасибо

**UPDATE**

Ссылку на видео получаю с помощью
https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?videos=-63632654_456261113&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&v=5.73

-63632654_456261113 - ID видео

При данном запросе получаю в ответ JSON:

```
{"response":{"count":1,"items":[{"can_comment":1,"can_like":1,"can_repost":1,"can_subscribe":1,"can_add_to_faves":1,"can_add":1,"comments":3,"date":1590530075,"description":"[club63632654| Viral Video] - https:\/\/vk.com\/viralv\n[club63632654| Нажми сюда, чтобы подписаться!]","duration":35,"photo_130":"https:\/\/sun6-22.userapi.com\/ZtS8mktii-75c-6QvUKZjsgkH59tABt7uVAqmA\/oNZU7cwS71Q.jpg","photo_320":"https:\/\/sun6-22.userapi.com\/rgo2WcVKmSE0idNDMrR3_N8ASUhaNF3GHrOKmg\/RWeEeJSAcb8.jpg","photo_800":"https:\/\/sun6-22.userapi.com\/FyEt6wiGXE9I139VoFyOp8xo_bBm--jvM-Axuw\/fL5EQRZD3ec.jpg","photo_1280":"https:\/\/sun6-22.userapi.com\/VmAsObNWtNgQaMO1bj2F7yclFsxpIfEUDg350A\/Jt4B0BS5xOg.jpg","first_frame_130":"https:\/\/sun6-22.userapi.com\/rcwolzfaTwQBLvJxCE3CBsEZvkTIBdTNYgF4KA\/Uq19jdNNQMg.jpg","first_frame_160":"https:\/\/sun6-20.userapi.com\/V8hJ6XbRJ9iiSS4kmVAWhLr5qhAMCh5-olw7KA\/Fag7cPJDdhM.jpg","first_frame_320":"https:\/\/sun6-22.userapi.com\/skqcMByrigx7v50Vvwa0rpT3muFNRdQKiGjZyg\/IUg2jFwPoAo.jpg","first_frame_800":"https:\/\/sun6-21.userapi.com\/I64cfJV9uMn4rUFH-TQktHzuh4OJJgCGEAZUEg\/1UPSgOIinHc.jpg","first_frame_1280":"https:\/\/sun6-20.userapi.com\/jq2f3hUHFluoYSkyv1bpayIi79PUl_V5R4uyoA\/CB_zg4uAS2A.jpg","width":496,"height":480,"id":456261113,"owner_id":-63632654,"title":"Журналисты не оставят в покое","player":"https:\/\/vk.com\/video_ext.php?oid=-63632654&id=456261113&hash=75d087e04edecbfe&__ref=vk.android&api_hash=1606069017307142bc17acacc38f_GMYDEMRRHEYTCNY","repeat":1,"views":163982}]}}
```

**player** - тут ссылка на видео.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы создали такие же условия для скачивания, какие создаются в браузере? User-Agent, куки, другие заголовки запроса, по которым возвращантся видео-поток. Ссылку вы в сетевом логе браузера взяли или просто со страницы? Если второе, то делайте первое. И при чем здесь `vkontakte-api`, если вы к ней не обращаетесь?

Comment: @aepot дополнил первое сообщение, описал как получаю видео

Comment: Читаем [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/objects/video) и видим: `player: URL страницы с плеером, который можно использовать для воспроизведения ролика в браузере. Поддерживается flash и html5, плеер всегда масштабируется по размеру окна.`. Где вы тут увидели прямую ссылку на скачивание?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в том то и дело что прямой ссылки не увидел, в документации ничего не нашел, поиск по форумах результат тоже не дал, в логе браузера прямой ссылки не увидел, поэтому и пишу сюда:)

Comment: Если ничего не помогает, то прочитайте еще раз мой первый комментарий, там есть решение, вы его просто не заметили (или намеренно проигнорировали).

Comment: Хм, интересно, а почему я в логе браузера прямую ссылку увидел? Даже больше скажу, ей прям [весь лог забивает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cw8e.png)...